# Setting and updating center and zoom from external dropdown menu in React Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying write a function which will immediately recenter and rezoom my Leaflet map based on a data input which is updated using a dropdown menu above the map.  Currently this feature only works intermittently and only ever recenters based on the data from the previous selection.  My code is below.

App component:

```
import { React, Fragment, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from './components/header'
import Control from './components/control'
import Map from './components/map'
import Data from './data/data'

function App() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState()
  // const [center, setCenter] = useState()
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(8)
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('Show all')

  const filterOptions = ['Show all', 'Test 1', 'Test 2']

  let data = Data.filter((item) => item.group.includes(filter))

  const recalcCenter = () => {
    let long =
      data.reduce((total, next) => total + next.coordinates.long, 0) /
      data.length

    let lat =
      data.reduce((total, next) => total + next.coordinates.lat, 0) /
      data.length

    return [long, lat]
  }

  const displayPosition = useCallback(() => {
    map.setView(recalcCenter(), zoom)
    map.fitBounds(data.coordinates.getBounds())
  }, [map, filter])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Control
        onClick={displayPosition}
        setFilter={setFilter}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
      />
      <Map setMap={setMap} center={recalcCenter()} zoom={zoom} data={data} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default App
```

Control component:

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './control.module.css'

const Control = (props) => {
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    props.setFilter(event.target.value)
    // props.onClick()
  }

  let optionItems = props.filterOptions.map((item) => (
    <option key={item}>{item}</option>
  ))

  return (
    <div className={classes.control_container}>
      <p>Choose an option:</p>
      <select onChange={changeHandler}>{optionItems}</select>
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Control
```

Comment: So which function does not work as you would like?

Comment: I guess the it's the recalcCenter and displayPosition functions which aren't working as I would like.  At the moment the changeHandler updates the filter and the data points display on the map correctly, however, the map doesn't recenter immediately and calculated center is updated to the average position of the previous points.

Comment: Is this possible that the `data` is not refreshing correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's the data as the correct markers are showing on the map when the filter is updated.  I think it's an issue with the state of the center variable which seems to be one step behind the rest of the App. I've tried using useEffect to force it to recalculate every time the filter changes but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think you're missing `zoom` in the `const displayPosition = useCallback(...` dependencies array.

Comment: btw for optimization purposes, you could change `recalcCenter` to the one with `useCallback` usage too, but you must remember about the dependencies array :)